# Doubleclick DataGridViewrow show permanently the new datat in datagrv in other form

Tags: datagridview, row, double-click

hi everyone please a little help for me
everything work perfectly but i want when i click the row in form2 the datagridview in form1 display permanently :
- when load the programme i went from form1 to form2 by pressing a button
-in form2 i click to show up the data from database in datagridv
-when i click in showed data in datagridviewrow i show form1 by celldoubleclicked
-when return to form1 with clicked row(here my problem:it will not show the data in datagridv in form1 that showed up first time it will show it in same form when it loaded again)
i wish its clear

Comment: Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
        Dim form As New Form1
        form.str = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
        Me.Hide()
        form.Show()
    End Sub

Comment: this is how i get the clicked row in form 2

Comment: please who can help